# ember-simple-auth is not saving auth response to session

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, auth0

I'm using ember-simple-auth and I can see that the authentication token is returned and that my custom authenticator is putting it (code-wise) into the session.

I can use wireshark to see that the token comes back but I can't debug into the authenticator code - I can't even use debug statements as the redirect wipes the network session on google chrome.

However, it isn't in the session (google chrome tools)  and the session isn't considered authenticated.

Why is the lock code correctly popping up the auth0 dialog but not saving the session? I don't really think it is something with this code but rather a config or initialization setting I'm unaware of.

I expect the session to be saved in the _setupFutureEvents as the first thing it does.

Any ideas what I can try to get it to work?

(/app/authenticators/lock.js) authenticate (options) {

```
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((res) => {
      this.get('lock').show(options, (err, profile, jwt, accessToken, state, refreshToken) => {
        if (err) {
          this.onAuthError(err);
        } else {
          var sessionData = { profile, jwt, accessToken, refreshToken };

          // pass the NEW auth0 session data into future events
          this.afterAuth(sessionData).then(response => res(this._setupFutureEvents(response)));
        }
      });
    });
  },
  afterAuth (data) {
    return Ember.RSVP.resolve(data);
  },
  _setupFutureEvents (data) {

    // set the session info here
    this.get('sessionData').setProperties(data);
    this._clearJobs();
    this._scheduleExpire();

    if (this.get('hasRefreshToken')) {
      this._scheduleRefresh();
    }

    return this.get('sessionData');
  },
```

Comment: You can use preserve log in network / console in chrome debugger tools (it should be a checkbox on the top) to preserve your debug statements and network activity.

Comment: Also I suggest you try to log in the event handlers for afterAuth and log through Authenticate there might be an error. Also which version of lock are you using Lock 10 or Lock 9 ?

Comment: "auth0-lock": "^10.0.2" via bower

Comment: I forgot about preserve log - thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Tried preserving log - that doesn't work. No ember logging inside the authentication stuff. The ember debug viewer in chrome also says there is an unknown mixin - which I assuem is the authenticator.

Comment: Can you assign event listeners to lock for `authorization_error`, `unrecoverable_error` ?